# Displaying Image On SmallBASIC

Tags: image, image-processing, file-io, basic

I want to display a image using [SmallBASIC](http://smallbasic.sourceforge.net). For this I've started by searching on the references, then I found a reference for [IMAGE](http://smallbasic.sourceforge.net/?q=node/617), that is like this:

```
IMAGE #handle, index, x, y [,sx,sy [,w,h]]
```

Then I found another to open files([OPEN](http://smallbasic.sourceforge.net/?q=node/594)):

```
OPEN file [FOR {INPUT|OUTPUT|APPEND}] AS #fileN
```

But I want to know some things:

- What image types this function can display?
- There is any real example to use IMAGE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The supported image formats are xpm, jpeg, png and gif. For an example of the IMAGE command's use, check out the welcome.bas source code included with the FLTK build of SmallBASIC.